# How to run and display the results from a program running on a server?

Tags: web, client, server

I have coded an algorithm that will give a numerical value.

I want any client browser to access this software running it in a server, execute it, and display the results on the web page - how do I do it?
- what special requirements for the software on the server?
- how to make sure that a client from www will go to the server where the program is running?
- there might be multiple clients accessing at the same time?
- different browers and OSs and possibly tablets?

I am a newbie and I am looking for tutorial, examples etc?
Thanks

**Update:**
What is the preferred language for the program, python, C or C++?
My responsibility is just giving the program details - the party who does the web will hook it. So my questions are will giving simple executable is sufficient not an API? How do I set it up on a server? How my partner knows how to access my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is fun and easy:

```
echo exec("myscript.exe");
```

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/12/0

Comment: Doing so will allow any client computer to go to a browser to run it?  Also what is the preferred language for the program, python, C or C++?

Comment: Anyone that can reach your web page could run it :)  PHP is a language (which is based on C) http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use WCF restful service if you are a .Net developer
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/803409/REST-enabled-WCF-service

Comment: I am a Unix guy mostly